# Optimize for - if loops

Tags: python, for-loop

I am writing this question using python but it may apply to any programming language. I would like to know if there is a more efficient way to write the following code:

```
for x in range(9):
    if x == 5:        
        list_ = [101, 102]
        for x in list_:
            print(x)
    else:   
        print(x)
```

I would be happy not to have to repeat `print(x)`

Comment: There is nothing wrong with calling the same function in more than one place. In fact, it does not even print the same variable `x`.

Comment: Not repeating `print(x)` won't change the efficiency of this code, because there's an `if`/`else` here.

Comment: I just wonder if there is a better way than nesting for-if loops, which are useful and understandable. The goal of the question is to learn

Answer (score 2):

Not repeating `print(x)` won't change the efficiency of this code, because there's an `if`/`else` here so every number is printed exactly once.

You can write it shorter, for example:

```
for x in [*range(5), 101, 102, *range(6, 9)]:
    print(x)
```

Or even:

```
for x in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 101, 102, 6, 7, 8]:
    print(x)
```

Which I have added here just in order to illustrate that your question doesn't seem like a real problem to deal with in the first place...

Answer (score -1):

This doesn't shorten the code... it may be a bit slower depending on what you are doing in your real application, but its a common technique to stage a call in one step and make the call in another. This is especially useful if you have common post-call processing. Its a bit of overkill for this example though

```
for x in range(9):
    if x == 5:        
        list = [101, 102]
    else:
        list = [x]
    for x in list:
        print(x)
```